# R Summary stats by column of data table

Tags: r, loops, datatable

I want to create a data dictionary for a data table with 50+ columns. To start, I want to create summary object, data table or similar, that has one row per column in the source data table, with columns showing the earliest and latest non-missing value, minimum and maximum values, number of missing values, etc. I tried to do this by looping over the columns of my source data table, but I cannot get the calculations to work. Here is a simplified version of my code, plus a chunk of code that does what I want, but without the loop:

```
require("data.table")

dtTest <- data.table(dObsDt = c("2020-08-01","2020-08-02","2020-08-03")
                 , nPrcp.LAKE = c(NA,12,13)
                 , nPrcp.PLAT = c(NA,NA,33)
)
dtTest

# Using loop
# Runs without error but does not produce desired results
vsCols <- colnames(dtTest)
dtColDesc <- data.table()
for (lasCol in vsCols) {
  ldtVar <- data.table()
  ladEarliest <- dtTest[!is.na(eval(lasCol)),list(dLatest=min(dObsDt))][[1]]
  lanMax <- dtTest[!is.na(eval(lasCol)),list(dMax=max(eval(lasCol)))][[1]]
  ldtVar[,':=' (sColName = lasCol
                , nMax = lanMax
                , dEarliest = ladEarliest
  )]
  dtColDesc <- rbind(dtColDesc, ldtVar, fill=TRUE)
}
dtColDesc

# Remove loop
# Runs without error and produces desired results but not scalable
vsCols <- colnames(dtTest)
dtColDesc <- data.table()

ldtVar <- data.table()
ladEarliest <- dtTest[!is.na(dObsDt),list(dLatest=min(dObsDt))][[1]]
lanMax <- dtTest[!is.na(dObsDt),list(dMax=max(dObsDt))][[1]]
ldtVar[,':=' (sColName = lasCol
              , nMax = lanMax
              , dEarliest = ladEarliest
)]
dtColDesc <- rbind(dtColDesc, ldtVar, fill=TRUE)

ldtVar <- data.table()
ladEarliest <- dtTest[!is.na(nPrcp.LAKE),list(dLatest=min(dObsDt))][[1]]
lanMax <- dtTest[!is.na(nPrcp.LAKE),list(dMax=max(nPrcp.LAKE))][[1]]
ldtVar[,':=' (sColName = lasCol
              , nMax = lanMax
              , dEarliest = ladEarliest
)]
dtColDesc <- rbind(dtColDesc, ldtVar, fill=TRUE)

ldtVar <- data.table()
ladEarliest <- dtTest[!is.na(nPrcp.PLAT),list(dLatest=min(dObsDt))][[1]]
lanMax <- dtTest[!is.na(nPrcp.PLAT),list(dMax=max(nPrcp.PLAT))][[1]]
ldtVar[,':=' (sColName = lasCol
              , nMax = lanMax
              , dEarliest = ladEarliest
)]
dtColDesc <- rbind(dtColDesc, ldtVar, fill=TRUE)

dtColDesc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the single-column stats, both of the other proposed solutions work well. For the two-column stats, this may not be the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
vsCols <- colnames(dtTest)
dtColDesc <- data.table()
for (lasCol in vsCols) {
  ldtVar <- data.table()
  ladEarliest <- dtTest[!is.na(dtTest[[lasCol]]),list(dEarliest=min(dObsDt))][[1]]
  ladLatest <- dtTest[!is.na(dtTest[[lasCol]]),list(dLatest=max(dObsDt))][[1]]
  ldtVar[,':=' (sColName = lasCol
                , dEarliest = ladEarliest
                , dLatest = ladLatest
  )]
  dtColDesc <- rbind(dtColDesc, ldtVar, fill=TRUE)
}
dtColDesc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do broadly what you want with something like this:

```
data.table(sColName = colnames(dtTest),
           max = sapply(dtTest, max, na.rm=T),
           min = sapply(dtTest, min, na.rm=T),
           median = sapply(dtTest, median, na.rm=T),
           nmissing = sapply(dtTest, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
)
```

*However* be aware that you're going to end up with more than one data type in each column, which will mean that most of your columns end up storing numbers and dates all as characters. Not a huge deal if this is just for a quick summary, but problematic if you want to pass this data onto other things.

Comment: Thanks. That gets me most of the way, but I need to find the earliest (min dObsDt) and latest (max dObsDt) non-missing value for each variable, which I don't this approach will do. Am I missing something?

Comment: My answer was just an example of the general approach :-) You can add lines for any other operation you might want to do. For example `earliest = sapply(dtTest, function(x){ first(x[!is.na(x)]) }`

Comment: As I understand the way sapply works when applied to a data table, it pulls out each column as a vector and allows me to do calculations, which gives me most of the descriptive stats I need, but I don't think it will allow me to do the earliest and latest calculations. For those values, I need to do calculation on two column: find the minimum and maximum values of one column, dObsDt, for all rows with a non-missing value of another column, in this case nPrcp.PLAT, and do that for each of the 50+ columns.

Comment: sapply will handle that just fine: you can use it to send other, static, arguments to your function. So if you extend the function to take a second column (the date) then you can always pass that column as the second function argument. i.e. `earliest = sapply(dtTest, function(x){ ... }, dtTest$MyDateCol)`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I can't get it to work. I've tried every combination of commas, round brackets, and curly brackets I can think of, and I can't get sapply to use both the "loop" column and the date column. Any chance you could point me to a resource that would lay that out in detail?

Comment: I'm not aware of any resources like that, sorry: I just use the sapply help file. You can get the gist by running `sapply(1:3, sum, 10)`, which is equivalent to `sum(1, 10); sum(2, 10); sum(3, 10)`. In your case, this should do the job: `earliest2 = sapply(dtTest, function(x, y){ z <- x[order(y)]; first(z[!is.na(z)])}, dtTest$dObsDt)`

Answer (score 1):

For information other than the earliest and latest non missing value in a data frame, the `describe()` function from the `psych` package generates a table where the columns from an input data frame are in rows, and various descriptive statistics are represented in columns. We illustrate with the `mtcars` data frame:

```
library(psych)
describe(mtcars)


> describe(mtcars)
     vars  n   mean     sd median trimmed    mad   min    max  range  skew
mpg     1 32  20.09   6.03  19.20   19.70   5.41 10.40  33.90  23.50  0.61
cyl     2 32   6.19   1.79   6.00    6.23   2.97  4.00   8.00   4.00 -0.17
disp    3 32 230.72 123.94 196.30  222.52 140.48 71.10 472.00 400.90  0.38
hp      4 32 146.69  68.56 123.00  141.19  77.10 52.00 335.00 283.00  0.73
drat    5 32   3.60   0.53   3.70    3.58   0.70  2.76   4.93   2.17  0.27
wt      6 32   3.22   0.98   3.33    3.15   0.77  1.51   5.42   3.91  0.42
qsec    7 32  17.85   1.79  17.71   17.83   1.42 14.50  22.90   8.40  0.37
vs      8 32   0.44   0.50   0.00    0.42   0.00  0.00   1.00   1.00  0.24
am      9 32   0.41   0.50   0.00    0.38   0.00  0.00   1.00   1.00  0.36
gear   10 32   3.69   0.74   4.00    3.62   1.48  3.00   5.00   2.00  0.53
carb   11 32   2.81   1.62   2.00    2.65   1.48  1.00   8.00   7.00  1.05
     kurtosis    se
mpg     -0.37  1.07
cyl     -1.76  0.32
disp    -1.21 21.91
hp      -0.14 12.12
drat    -0.71  0.09
wt      -0.02  0.17
qsec     0.34  0.32
vs      -2.00  0.09
am      -1.92  0.09
gear    -1.07  0.13
carb     1.26  0.29
>
```

The earliest and latest non missing values can be added a combination of `sapply()` as noted in the other answer, and `pastecs::first()` or `pastecs::last()`. When we set the argument `na.rm = TRUE` on these functions, they retrieve the first (or last) non-missing value.

```
summaryDf <- describe(mtcars)
library(pastecs)
summaryDf$earliest <- sapply(mtcars, function(x) { first(x,na.rm=TRUE)})
summaryDf$latest <- sapply(mtcars, function(x) {last(x,na.rm=TRUE)})
```

...and the output:

```
> summaryDf
     vars  n   mean     sd median trimmed    mad   min    max  range  skew
mpg     1 32  20.09   6.03  19.20   19.70   5.41 10.40  33.90  23.50  0.61
cyl     2 32   6.19   1.79   6.00    6.23   2.97  4.00   8.00   4.00 -0.17
disp    3 32 230.72 123.94 196.30  222.52 140.48 71.10 472.00 400.90  0.38
hp      4 32 146.69  68.56 123.00  141.19  77.10 52.00 335.00 283.00  0.73
drat    5 32   3.60   0.53   3.70    3.58   0.70  2.76   4.93   2.17  0.27
wt      6 32   3.22   0.98   3.33    3.15   0.77  1.51   5.42   3.91  0.42
qsec    7 32  17.85   1.79  17.71   17.83   1.42 14.50  22.90   8.40  0.37
vs      8 32   0.44   0.50   0.00    0.42   0.00  0.00   1.00   1.00  0.24
am      9 32   0.41   0.50   0.00    0.38   0.00  0.00   1.00   1.00  0.36
gear   10 32   3.69   0.74   4.00    3.62   1.48  3.00   5.00   2.00  0.53
carb   11 32   2.81   1.62   2.00    2.65   1.48  1.00   8.00   7.00  1.05
     kurtosis    se earliest latest
mpg     -0.37  1.07    21.00  21.40
cyl     -1.76  0.32     6.00   4.00
disp    -1.21 21.91   160.00 121.00
hp      -0.14 12.12   110.00 109.00
drat    -0.71  0.09     3.90   4.11
wt      -0.02  0.17     2.62   2.78
qsec     0.34  0.32    16.46  18.60
vs      -2.00  0.09     0.00   1.00
am      -1.92  0.09     1.00   1.00
gear    -1.07  0.13     4.00   4.00
carb     1.26  0.29     4.00   2.00
>
```

We can verify the behavior of the non-missing values by setting the first & last rows of the data frame to `NA`, and rerunning the calculations.

```
mtcars[c(1,32),] <- NA 
summaryDf$earliest = sapply(mtcars, function(x){ first(x,na.rm=TRUE) })
summaryDf$latest <- sapply(mtcars, function(x) {last(x,na.rm=TRUE)})
summaryDf
mtcars[c(2,31),]
```

...and the output, illustrating that the first and last values have been taken from rows 2 and 31 instead of 1 and 32:

```
> summaryDf
     vars  n   mean     sd median trimmed    mad   min    max  range  skew
mpg     1 32  20.09   6.03  19.20   19.70   5.41 10.40  33.90  23.50  0.61
cyl     2 32   6.19   1.79   6.00    6.23   2.97  4.00   8.00   4.00 -0.17
disp    3 32 230.72 123.94 196.30  222.52 140.48 71.10 472.00 400.90  0.38
hp      4 32 146.69  68.56 123.00  141.19  77.10 52.00 335.00 283.00  0.73
drat    5 32   3.60   0.53   3.70    3.58   0.70  2.76   4.93   2.17  0.27
wt      6 32   3.22   0.98   3.33    3.15   0.77  1.51   5.42   3.91  0.42
qsec    7 32  17.85   1.79  17.71   17.83   1.42 14.50  22.90   8.40  0.37
vs      8 32   0.44   0.50   0.00    0.42   0.00  0.00   1.00   1.00  0.24
am      9 32   0.41   0.50   0.00    0.38   0.00  0.00   1.00   1.00  0.36
gear   10 32   3.69   0.74   4.00    3.62   1.48  3.00   5.00   2.00  0.53
carb   11 32   2.81   1.62   2.00    2.65   1.48  1.00   8.00   7.00  1.05
     kurtosis    se earliest latest
mpg     -0.37  1.07    21.00  15.00
cyl     -1.76  0.32     6.00   8.00
disp    -1.21 21.91   160.00 301.00
hp      -0.14 12.12   110.00 335.00
drat    -0.71  0.09     3.90   3.54
wt      -0.02  0.17     2.88   3.57
qsec     0.34  0.32    17.02  14.60
vs      -2.00  0.09     0.00   0.00
am      -1.92  0.09     1.00   1.00
gear    -1.07  0.13     4.00   5.00
carb     1.26  0.29     4.00   8.00
> mtcars[c(2,31),]
              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Maserati Bora  15   8  301 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```